# iBeacon: Foreground monitoring interval (didDetermineStateForRegion)

Tags: cordova, monitoring, ibeacon

I want to get an alert call when users enter into a region. I managed to get the "inside" alert immediately when users entered into the region. However, it takes around 20 seconds to get the "outside" alert call when users exit from the region, even though the app is working in the foreground. What can I do to get the "outside" alert call immediately right after the users exit from the region?

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
delegate.didDetermineStateForRegion = function(pluginResult) {
            var flag = pluginResult.state;
            if(flag == "CLRegionStateInside"){
                alert("inside");
            }else if(flag == "CLRegionStateOutside"){
                alert("outside");
            };
};`
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS notifies about user leaving the region after a timeout since the last beacon has been seen. This behaviour is present to avoid frequent entry/exit events if a beacon is not seen a few seconds for some reason (e.g. interferences). Also a beacon is reported with RSSI `0` and proximity `Unknown` for 2-3 seconds even after turning the beacon off.

Comment: This is correct.  Understand that the only way that a mobile device can know if it has exited is if enough time passes without detecting a beacon packet.